# JAXB - Tag repetindo, ao invés de aninhar

Tags: java, xml

Estou com um problema que não consigo armazenar mais de um elemento na mesma TAG, olhem o XML:

```
<ItemCardapio>
    <nCdItemCardapio>10</nCdItemCardapio>
    <nQtdeItemCardapio>2</nQtdeItemCardapio>
    <ObsProducao>
        <sDsObservacaoProducao>Com Gelo</sDsObservacaoProducao>
    </ObsProducao>
    <ObsProducao>
        <sDsObservacaoProducao>Sem Açucar</sDsObservacaoProducao>
    </ObsProducao>
</ItemCardapio>
```

Como vocês podem ver, a TAG "ObsProducao" repete, ao invés de ficar assim:

```
<ItemCardapio>
    <nCdItemCardapio>10</nCdItemCardapio>
    <nQtdeItemCardapio>2</nQtdeItemCardapio>
    <ObsProducao>
        <sDsObservacaoProducao>Com Gelo</sDsObservacaoProducao>
        <sDsObservacaoProducao>Sem Açucar</sDsObservacaoProducao>
    </ObsProducao>
</itemcardapio>
```

Segue a classe com as anotações JAXB:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "nCdItemCardapio",
        "nQtdeItemCardapio",
        "obsProducao"
    })
    public static class ItemCardapio {

        protected int nCdItemCardapio;
        protected int nQtdeItemCardapio;
        @XmlElement(name = "ObsProducao")
        protected List<WsTSPaymentParamPedido.ItemCardapio.ObsProducao> obsProducao;
            ..........
```

Agora a classe que repete:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "sDsObservacaoProducao"
        })
        public static class ObsProducao {

            protected String sDsObservacaoProducao;
......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como sua classe `ObsProducao` é apenas um wrapper para uma `String`, você pode eliminá-la completamente:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "ObsProducao")
@XmlElement(name = "sDsObservacaoProducao")
protected List<String> obsProducao;
```

O `@XmlElementWrapper` gerará um *wrapper* chamado `ObsProducao`, o `@XmlElement` fará com que cada item dentro da lista gere um elemento chamado `sDsObservacaoProducao`, logo, o resultado será aquilo que você espera:

```
<ObsProducao>
    <sDsObservacaoProducao>Com Gelo</sDsObservacaoProducao>
    <sDsObservacaoProducao>Sem Açucar</sDsObservacaoProducao>
</ObsProducao>
```

Comment: Anthony funcionou perfeitamente :) ... mas como ficaria o XSD desse arquivo XML, pois do jeito que eu criei o XSD, quando gero as classes a partir dele o resultado do XML é aquele com a tag repetindo, dê uma olhada no meu xsd, por favor:

Comment: <xsd:element name="ItemCardapio" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
<xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="nCdItemCardapio" type="xsd:int" />
  <xsd:element name="nQtdeItemCardapio" type="xsd:int" />
  <xsd:element name="ObsProducao" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
   <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="sDsObservacaoProducao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>       
</xsd:element>

Comment: Você pode usar o [schemagen](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbcv.html) para gerar um xsd da sua classe e ver como o Java faz essa construção. De qualquer forma, se eu fosse gerar um XSD na mão (no geral eu evito isso) usaria um `xsd:complexType` para a lista (contendo uma sequência de strings `unbouded` cujo nome é `sDsObservacaoProducao`). O `ItemCardapio` teria um `xsd:element` chamado `ObsProducao` referenciando esse tipo complexo.

Comment: Deu certo diego? Se sim por favor aceite a resposta.

Comment: Deu sim, obrigado amigo :)